# Running Perl script on Hadoop

Tags: perl, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a Perl Script that generates data.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
{
        $str1 = "";
        $str2 = "";
        $str3 = "";
        $str4 = "";
        $str5 = "";
        $str6 = "";
        $str7 = "";
        $str8 = "";
        $str9 = "";
        @chars=('a'..'z','A'..'Z','_');
    for(1..10){
        $str1.=$chars[rand @chars];
        $str2 =$chars[rand @chars];
        $str3 =$chars[rand @chars];
        $str4 =$chars[rand @chars];
        $str5 =$chars[rand @chars];
        $str6 =$chars[rand @chars];
        $str7 =$chars[rand @chars];
        $str8 =$chars[rand @chars];
        $str9 =$chars[rand @chars];
    }
        print "$i:str1:str2:str3:str4:str5:str6:str7:str8:str9\n";
}
```

When I run the script using `Hadoop Streaming`, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin
hadoop fs -rm -R /user/oracle/output
echo "Start time :" `date` >> run_time_perl_hadoop.log
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/hadoop-0.20-        mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-D mapreduce.map.tasks=1 \
-input /user/oracle/perl_test/data_generator_hadoop_tarun.pl \
-output /user/oracle/output \
-mapper data_generator_hadoop_tarun.pl \
-file data_generator_hadoop_tarun.pl


echo "End time :" `date` >> run_time_perl_hadoop.log
```

It generates 6 Rows instead of 3 rows.

Any idea why?

Comment: Could you please properly edit the code so that it is readable

Comment: It looks like you start your script twice, once as mapper and once as option file.

Comment: Without file option it will not execute - Gives me error. I will have to pass the mapper class for the perl scrip to execute. Any Suggestions please?

Comment: Can anyone kindly suggest any idea?